# "(obj1.compareTo(obj2) <= 0) ? one:two" meaning?

Tags: java, graph, vertex, compareto

I'm using some code that I got from an online source for my graph theory portion of a chemical modeling project. I'm trying to make sense of this. What does the first line of code mean in regards to the class's decision of which is one overall? One is the first vertex, two is the second vertex of the class. I'm not well versed in Linear Algebra/Discrete Math, so avoid mathematically intense explanations if possible.

```
public Edge(Vertex one, Vertex two, int length){
    this.one = (one.getElement().compareTo(two.getElement()) <= 0) ? one : two;
    this.two = (this.one == one) ? two : one;
    this.length = length;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: That is the [Conditional Operator `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) also known as a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Answer (score 2):

It's poorly written. Two tests where one would do, and almost deliberate obscurity. It's just trying to assign the lesser vertex to `one` and the other one to `two`, so as to keep the edges consistently ordered. A clearer version would be:

```
public Edge(Vertex one, Vertex two, int length)
{
    if (one.getElement().compareTo(two.getElement()) <= 0)
    {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }
    else
    {
        this.one = two;
        this.two = one;
    }
    this.length = length;
}
```

Comment: Too many close-parens in `if` statement. Suggestion (for you and all programmers writing code like this): Add comment like this before `if` statement: `// Assign to fields, but assign vertex with lowest element to field "one"`.

Comment: @Andreas I doubt that I would do that, it seems clear enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not real sure what you are trying to do here but the first line is using the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface which, whatever `Vertex.getElement()` returns, implements.  If `one`'s element is "less than or equal" to `two`'s element then `this` edge's `one` is set to the given `one` otherwise it's set to `two`.  The second line then sets `this`'s `two` accordingly (i.e. if we decided `this.one = one` then `this.two = two` otherwise `this.one = two` and `this.two = one`).